# multiple global statements within function elifs

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

The program first asks the user if they'd like to load their own file or use the the file provided by the script.

```
filename=0
def first(filename):
    print('Please Select:')
    print('Run Program Now? Press "1"')
    start = int(input('Load Your Own List and Run Program? Press "2": '))

    if start ==1:
        global filename
        filename = 'file.txt'
    elif start ==2:
        import tkinter as tk
        from tkinter import filedialog

        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        global filename
        filename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()
    else:
        print("You didn't enter a valid selection!")
        first(filename)
    main()
```

I'm using another function which should call the correct file based on the user input.

```
def guess(real):
    WORDLIST = filename
    with open(WORDLIST, 'r') as in_file:
```

Error:

```
ErrorSyntaxError: name 'filename' is assigned to before global declaration
```

This all worked earlier when I had the user input and elif statements within

```
def guess(real):
```

Although I wanted to call it separately and that's why I have the user input in it's own function.

Comment: Why do you need *any* globals?

Comment: Sorry, I missed a line of code. (filename=0)
I would assume I need a global value to update the main value?
that is what I found during research.

Comment: No, you should be passing it into the functions that need it.

Comment: And then using `return` to use it outside of the function.

Comment: @DavidG I did try using 'return' but that also didn't work. But should I still need to use a return for a global? shouldn't it return it anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `return` with global variables, however I would avoid using global variables if possible. You might want to read "[why are global variables evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)" for more details.

A simplified version of the code you provided is shown below using `return` and then passing the result to another function to avoid using global variables:

```
def first():
    while True:
        print('Please Select:')
        print('Run Program Now? Press "1"')
        start = int(input('Load Your Own List and Run Program? Press "2": '))

        if start == 1:
            filename = 'file.txt'
            return filename
        elif start == 2:
            filename = 'hello.txt'
            return filename
        else:
            print("You didn't enter a valid selection!")

def second(filename):
    print (filename)

filename = first()
second(filename)
```